# Categorical explanatory variables in Poisson regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I want to perform a Poisson regression to explain Abundance (Counts of individuals) through a number of continuous and categorical explanatory variables. Some of the categorical variables have more than two levels so I will be performing some dummy coding as well.

The question I have is can generalised linear models can cope with multiple types of variables?

Comment: Yes, I think any linear model can cope with multiple types of variables.

Comment: Yes, just as with regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can. The linear component of a GLM can contain whatever a standard linear model can, the difference of course being the distribution of the response and the need for a link function. So go ahead and fit your model but be mindful of the interpretation.